# In SAS how do i assign a macro variable to the current week number?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm assigning a macro variable as such:
 %let weeks2=31 ;

but instead of 31 i want the variable to automatically be the current weeknumber.

I've tried using weeks2=week(today(), 'u') but this returns an error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the right idea. However, you are trying to use SAS functions (`week` and `today`) in a macro statement (`%let`). When doing so, you have to call **each** SAS function using the `%sysfunc` macro function:

```
%let weeks2=%sysfunc(week(%sysfunc(today()), u));
```

Also, arguments need not be quoted in macro functions (the `u` argument in this case).